# Convert OpenGL canvas coordinates to HTML5 canvas coordinates

Tags: html, opengl, canvas, applet, html5-canvas

I'm have a Java Applet OpenGL simulation and I'm trying to convert
to a HTML5 canvas. Anyone know how can I convert these coordinates?

OpenGL get from -400x to +400x and from -600y to +600y,
while my canvas get from 0x to 400x and from 0y to 600y
without negative coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple linear function you need to have. Linear functions have the form `f(x) = m * x + n`

For the x-coordinate:

You want to map -400 to 0 and 400 to 400, so you have two points (-400, 0), (400, 400) that describe your linear relation.

You now compute the gradient m with (y2-y1)/(x2-x1), in this example: m = (400-0)/(400--400) = 1/2

So your function now looks like: f(x) = 1/2 * x + n

To compute n (the y-intercept) you just insert a point (e. g. (-400, 0)):

0 = 1/2 * (-400) + n

You get n as 200. So the final function is `f(x) = 1/2 * x + 200`

For the y-coordinate you get `g(y) = 1/2 * y + 300`

Comment: I'm try to make this, but doesn't work      

`var x = ?;
var glMinX = -470;
var glMaxX = 470;
var canvasMinX = 0;
var canvasMaxX = 480;

var gradient = (glMinX - glMaxX) / (canvasMinX - canvasMaxX);
var slope = gradient * glMinX;
var yIntercept = glMaxX - slope; 
var newX = gradientM * x * yIntercept;`

Comment: you want to map glMinX to canvasMinX => Point (-470, 0) (this is (x1, y1))  
and you want to map glMaxX to canvasMaxX => Point (470, 480) (this is (x2, y2))  
gradient = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = (480-0)/(470--470) = 24/47  
so `gradient = (canvasMaxX-canvasMinX)/(glMaxX-glMinX)`
and `yIntercept = canvasMinX - gradient * glMinX` (or canvasMaxX - gradient * glMaxX)  
in this example: yIntercept = 0 - 47/47 * (- 470) = 240  
  
you get your function as f(x) = gradient * x + yIntercept  
so: `f(x) = 24/47 * x + 240`  
now f(-470) = 0 and f(470) = 480  
in code:  

newX = gradient * x + yIntercept

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, but these comment fields don't let you insert line breaks

Comment: Thank you so much, work very well. You help-me alot, thank-you again.